# Downgrading from AWS Aurora MySQL 5.7 to AWS Aurora MySQL 5.6

Tags: mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, aws-aurora

We are trying to downgrade from AWS Aurora MySQL 5.7 to AWS Aurora MySQL 5.6 due to some issues. But AWS RDS doesn't allow Aurora MySQL 5.7 snapshot restore to Aurora MySQL 5.6 instance/cluster. Does anyone face same problem? How can we restore it to old version?

Thanks,
Sagun

Comment: Using Queries may be your only option, Can you export the databases, tables, indices and data to files?  If you can then just build it step by step.  If you cannot, please update what your goal/method/issues are.

Answer (score 2):

I think exporting to a SQL file first would work:

- export to a SQL file (in S3 or elsewhere)
- import to a 5.6 instance

See this: [Amazon Aurora Can Export Data into Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/06/amazon-aurora-can-export-data-into-amazon-s3/), where it says:

> **You can now use the `SELECT INTO OUTFILE S3` SQL statement to query data from an Amazon Aurora database cluster and save it directly into text files** in an Amazon S3 bucket. This means you no longer need the two-step process of bringing the data to the SQL client and then copying it from the client to Amazon S3. **It’s an easy way to export data** selectively to Amazon Redshift or any other application.
>   ...